# How to access data from observables in angular using httpClient?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to connect to API with my angular app and I want to create a get function that returns an array.
Connecting works fine, but the function doesn't return what I want.

Here's code.

```
export class ApiService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public getUsers() {
    const res = this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/user');
    res.subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);
      return response;
    });
  }
}
```

console.log() prints an array, but when I try to do `users = this.getUsers();` and console.log() it, it prints ZoneAwarePromise instead.

[ZoneAwarePromise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOYpg.png)

Comment: Calling an asynchronous method doesn't return a value instead you can make a call back function

Comment: You do not subscribe in the service, the service returns observable and your component subscribes to the returned observable on function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return the obserable and await it in your component, here is an example:

Service

```
GetUser(): Observable<UserObject> {
    return this.http.get<UserObject>(url) 
}
```

And in your component you can await by doing the following:

```
getUserInfo() {
    this.dataService.GetUser().subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);
    }, error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`HttpClient.get` returns an Observable, that's why you need to subscribe to get its content. So, this assign you're trying to do is not correct, your method does not return the array you want.

A common way to to this, considering that `this.users` is at component level would be:

`.service`

```
getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
  return this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/user');
}
```

`.component`

```
users: User[];

ngOnInit {
  this.service.getUsers()
    .subscribe(users => this.users = users);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below . It should work fine

```
export class ApiService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public getUsers() {
    const res = this.http.get('http://localhost:3000/user').subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response);
      return response;
    });
  }
}
```